# query on large size table takes up a lot of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have Table `ArchiveArseh` with size 15GB and 198997 row record with engine innoDB(and in the future 400G and 1000000 record).

This Table contain image(field `document`,`thumbDocument`).
[image]

on filed(`Id`) is primary key and 4 field are indexed.
[image]

explain 
[image]
[image]

when run simple query select like

```
SELECT *
FROM archivearseh
WHERE CONCAT(BlockCode,ArsehRow)='01011000106001'
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM archivearseh
WHERE BlockCode='106001' and ArsehRow='01011000'
```

get 2 min to return result?!

how can decrease time run query?

Comment: what mean `15G and 198997 record` ?

Comment: 15G has size my table that have 190000 record

Comment: You mean 15 GB ? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: i add image explain to my question

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please help me please...

Comment: Add the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and you will see your query doesnt use the index, because your `WHERE` condition isnt `SARGEABLE`

Comment: Your second query is slow because you dont have composite index and I dont see index for `BlockCode` Neither

Comment: You're sure that you want to store files in the database instead of the file system? Generally, for files over a few k in size, this is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `WHERE` isnt **[SARGEABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)**

```
 WHERE CONCAT(BlockCode,ArsehRow)='01011000106001'
```

So **CANT** use index, and has to calculate the `CONCAT` for every row

So either you create a trigger on update/insert to update a column and index that field so search will be faster (but update/insert will be slower).

```
 SET NewColumn = CONCAT(BlockCode,ArsehRow)
 CREATE INDEX for NewColumn;

 and 

 WHERE NewColumn = '01011000106001'
```

or do something to reduce the search domain like

```
WHERE BlockCode LIKE '010110%'
  AND CONCAT(BlockCode,ArsehRow)='01011000106001'
```

Comment: no, with `WHERE BlockCode='01011000' and ArsehRow='100100'`  still get a lot of time....

Comment: show me the explain analyze. Did you create composite index for `(BlockCode, ArsheRow)`, but even if those are slow that may be for different reasons... the query you ask still isnt `SARGEABLE` and will be slow

Comment: yes , `ShahrdariId` and `IdDarkhast` and `BlockCode` and `ArsehRow` together has one index

Comment: I dont see that on your question. Show me `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` in my comment i give you the link to teach you how, in case you dont know

Comment: That picture doesnt show the composite index for `(BlockCode, ArsheRow)`

Comment: @chatkai: Once you have created the composite index you should use the query with the AND clause rather than CONCAT to search. Also moving to MyIsam Database engine is suggested in case this table is going to be searched more often than updated.

Comment: you mean this ? `ALTER TABLE archivearseh
 ADD INDEX BlockCode_ArsehRow (BlockCode, ArsehRow);` create the composite index

Comment: yes, that is one of  the ways to create an index. The other one being:
CREATE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON TABLE_NAME(COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2);

Comment: You the query with `WHERE .... AND ... ` should improve with the composite index. But again the one with `CONCAT` doesnt because as I explain, isnt `SARGABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the table with columns BlockCode and ArsehRow.

Comment: BlockCode and ArsehRow current have index

Comment: @chatkai: Could you please create an index as : CREATE IDX_1 ON TABLE_NAME (BLOCKCODE, ARSEHROW); and then use explain SELECT * YOUR QUERY to see if the index id getting used.